# How to send form multi select values as a string with leading zeros in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a situation where I am trying to take the values out of a form multiple select and send them off as a concatenated string rather that as an array. The values for the multi select box would be like this:

- 11111
- 222222
- 333333

I would like the values to have a leading zero if under 6 chars (012345) which is done below: (these are two different variations)

```
    foreach ($_POST["book"] as $books)
        {
            $book = $book.str_pad($books, 0, 6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
    foreach ($_POST["book"] as $books)
        {
            $book .= str_pad(substr($books, 0), 6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
```

My goal is to have these concat together as a string like:

- 011111222222333333

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I keep getting the PHP error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Any guidance is highly appreciated. I have been searching for some answers with no luck.

```
<select multiple name="book" id="book" size="3">
  <option value="11111" selected="selected">11111</option>
  <option value="222222">222222</option>
  <option value="333333">333333</option>
</select>

$book = '';
$param[] = $bookList->getToolkitService()->AddParameterChar('both', 2500, 'book', 'book', $book);
```

Not sure if this is adequate information but the total string being sent off would be 2500 chars

Comment: Is `$_POST["book"]` actually an array? Best to show your form too.

Comment: please, show us your form

Comment: What does line 3 do? I have never seen it ever in my life.

Comment: Like @rjdown quoted, make sure your `$_POST["book"]` is an array. The error most probably is due to that reason. And for leading 0s, you could use something like: `$book = str_pad($book, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);` which will pad 0s to the left of your string, should their length be less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use name in select as: 
`<select name="book[]">`

In php:

```
  foreach ($_POST['book'] as $key => $book) {
    if(strlen($book)<6){
      for($i = 0; $i < 6-strlen($book); $i++){
        $_POST['book'][$key] = "0".$_POST['book'][$key];
      }
    }
  }
  $books = implode("", $_POST['book']);
```